# Hard to explain, A strange javascript mouseover issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mouseover

I have a box (the black bordered). I have a handler to trance the mouseout event of this box. The issue is when the mouse is hovered over an item let say div within this box ( the red bordered box, and the blue bordered box). The `mouseout` or mouseleave of the black bordered box event is fired.

I am googling for three days, but did not find any solution for this issue. Why the mouseleave/out event is fired within the box as mouse is within its boundary. The position of the div is "absolute". I tried with core JavaScript and JQuery.

Comment: Do you have a snippet of your code ?

Comment: Actually when I tried to post image with this question the system said that users having reputation less then 10 can not post images, really sorry for that

Comment: pot your source code here jsfiddle.net and send us the URL

Comment: Host the image somewhere, post URL and someone here will embed it inside the post.

Comment: I wish people would stop neg-voting questions like this. Give the guy a chance.

Comment: OK, here goes the code link:
http://jsfiddle.net/GXaNe/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.live` is deprecated, use `.on`

Also, using `mouseout` means that when the mouse leaves the selected element **OR** any of that elements children, the event is triggered. `mouseleave` applies only to the selected element.

```
  $('.nocMenuContainer').on('mouseleave',function(){     
       alert('bye');
  });
```

Comment: +1 You mean `mouseleave` applies only to the selected element.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there's not another selector on top of your button. For instance, if you have a div with padding and an  tag inside, the mouseleave event WILL fire when your mouse moves from the div to the  tag even though you're inside the . The solution? Add the border, mouseout, and padding directly to the  tag.

Comment: you can add padding and border to the <a> tag instead of the <div> tag, then change the event to be fired by the mouse hovering over the <a> tag instead of the <div> tag.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good documentation at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html#mouseover. It may help you to understand why the event is fired when moving the mouse inside you box; and it proposes a solution for distinguishing between external and internal moves.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but the browser is behaving quite normal. The `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events aren't propagating on all the overlaying dom elements as you would expect.
For cases when you need it to do so, I've developed a small [jQuery library called **superBind**](http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/fPHDF/).
As you can see in the example, the only difference is that you bind your events through the method `superBind` instead of the usual ones (`bind`,`live`,`on`.. and so on).
Hope this helps!